# {"level":"INFO","message":"[8:42:31.886 PM]: Easy Logging is disabled as no config has been found"}

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

getting error while connection snowflake through NodeJS.

I have specified account, username, password as options in snowflake.createConnection() function, do I have to specify any other options to make it work or else what can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.